# SAPUI5: Routing with parameters - How get correct path of binding context

Tags: javascript, json, routes, sapui5

I am trying to implement routing with parameters as in this walkthrough: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.58.7/#/topic/2366345a94f64ec1a80f9d9ce50a59ef

However, instead of getting data as a path

```
/Invoices(CustomerName='Alfreds%20Futterkiste',Discount=0f,OrderID=10835....
```

when they do:

```
oRouter.navTo("detail", {invoicePath: 
oItem.getBindingContext("invoice").getPath().substr(1)});
```

when I use the function in my controller (see onFwdDetail below), I only get a string path:

```
nodes/0
```

And this cannot be used in routing (see manifest.json below):

```
Invalid value "nodes/0" for segment "{detailPath}".
```

I am assuming it is because my JSON file is structured differently than in the walkthrough. How do I get the correct path with data for routing?

The relevant section of my implementation are as follows:

**Data.JSON**

```
{
"nodes": [
    {
        "text": "Text1",
        "status1": "Status10",
        "status2". "Status11"
    },
    {
        "text": "Text2",
        "status1": "Status20",
        "status2". "Status21"
    },...]
}
```

**Overview.view.xml**

```
<Table
    items="{path: 'mydata>/nodes'}">
...
<ColumnListItem type="Navigation" press="onFwdDetail">
```

**Overview.controller.js**

```
onInit : function() {
        var oModel = new JSONModel("model/Data.JSON");
        this.getView().setModel(oModel, "mydata");

    },
onFwdDetail : function(oEvent) {
        var oItem = oEvent.getSource();
        var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
        oRouter.navTo("detail", {detailPath: 
           oItem.getBindingContext("mydata").getPath().substr(1)});
        console.log(oItem.getBindingContext("mydata").getPath().substr(1));

    }
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
"pattern": "details/{detailPath}",
"name": "details",
"target": "details"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Their path is a path to an entity of an **OData** model. Your path is a path to an entity of a **JSON** model.

Those paths are built entirely different. Most importantly your path contains a slash, while theirs does not. This confuses the parser which tries to match `details/{detailPath}` and `details/nodes/0`.

The `0` itself is a valid path in your example. `nodes` is an array and it's possible to do `nodes[0]`. It's just that the routing class doesn't like the format.

So what you can do is simply passing the `0` to your `detailPath`. In your detail view you can then build the original key (`"nodes/" + detailPath`) and bind your view to that key.

I would also recommend this approach for OData btw:

- extract actual keys from bound object
- pass keys to your router
- in your detail view build a key from the passed arguments

---

Pseudo code for an OData model:

**Controller A:**

```
// read relevant values from binding context
var oContext = oItem.getBindingContext("myModel");
var sKeyName = oContext.getObject("CustomerName");
var sKeyId = oContext.getObject("OrderID");

// trigger navigation
oRouter.navTo("orderDetail", { name: sKeyName, id: sKeyId });
```

**Controller B:**

```
_onRouteMatched: function (oEvent) {
    var oModel = this.getModel("myModel");
    var that = this;

    // read params from routing
    var sKeyName = oEvent.getParameter("arguments").name;
    var sKeyId = oEvent.getParameter("arguments").id;

    // as soon as the metadata of the model are available there is a great API to build keys
    oModel.metadataLoaded().then(function () {

        var sPath = oModel.createKey("/Invoices", {
            CustomerName: sKeyName,
            OrderID: sKeyId
        });

        // sPath should be something like "/Invoices(CustomerName='Troll',OrderID=12345)"
        that.getView().bindElement({ path: sPath });

    });
},
```

**manifest.json**

```
"pattern": "order/{name},{id}",
"name": "orderDetail"
```